# ld can`t find libraries

Tags: directory, ld

Good afternoon,
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 64bits

I'm an electronics engineering student, and I'm doing some research with a team in the voice recognition area. I`m trying to install a software called bavieca: http://www.bavieca.org/

In order to install it I had to compile CBLAS and CLAPACK libraries, and then, in an archive called Makefile.defines I had to point the directories that contain the libraries.

After typing make in the source directory, I get the following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/reconhecimentode/bavieca-code/src/tools'
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack_LINUX
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas_LINUX3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas_LINUX
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas_LINUX
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [aligner] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/reconhecimentode/bavieca-code/src/tools'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is my Makefile.defines:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#  Copyright (C) 2012 Daniel Bolaños - www.bltek.com - Boulder Language Technologies           #
#                                                                                        
      #
#  www.bavieca.org is the website of the Bavieca Speech Recognition Toolkit                    #
#                                                                                              #
#  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");                             #
#  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.                            #
#  You may obtain a copy of the License at                                                     #
#                                                                                              #
#          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0                                          #
#                                                                                              #
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software                         #
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,                           #
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.                    #
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and                         #
#  limitations under the License.                                                              #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# ---------------------------------------
# Arch and Operating System settings
# ---------------------------------------

MAKE = make --quiet -w ARCH := $(shell uname -m | sed s/' '//g) OS  
:= $(shell uname -s)

# ---------------------------------------
# Linux compile options
# ---------------------------------------

XCC          = g++

# SIMD flags (vector based arithmetic operations)
#SIMD_FLAGS =
# SSE is enabled by default on gcc-4.0 and higher. If SSE is enabled, the C preprocessor symbol __SSE__ is defined SIMD_FLAGS = -msse3
# AVX is available on Sandy Bridge and later Intel and AMD architectures. If AVX is enabled the C preprocessor symbol __AVX__ is
defined
#SIMD_FLAGS = -march=corei7-avx


#CPPFLAGS     = -g -Wno-deprecated -Wall -O2 -finline-functions $(SIMD_FLAGS) CPPFLAGS     = -g -Wno-deprecated -O2 -finline-functions
$(SIMD_FLAGS)
# -fPIC generates Position Independent Code, which is needed to build shared libraries 
# so they can be dynamically relocated, however it may slowdown the code, for this reason
# it should be avoided for object files that build executables or static libraries CPPFLAGS_SHARED = $(CPPFLAGS) -fPIC AR        = ar rs

# ---------------------------------------
# CBLAS and LAPACK includes/libraries
# ---------------------------------------

BASE = /home/reconhecimentode

INCS_DIR_CBLAS = -I$(BASE)/CBLAS/include INCS_DIR_LAPACK =
-I$(BASE)/CLAPACK-3.2.1/INCLUDE LIBS_DIR_CBLAS = -L$(BASE)/CBLAS/lib -L$(BASE)/CLAPACK-3.2.1 LIBS_DIR_LAPACK = -L$(BASE)/CLAPACK-3.2.1 -L$(BASE)/CLAPACK-3.2.1/F2CLIBS LIB_CBLAS = -lcblas_LINUX -lblas_LINUX -lgfortran LIB_LAPACK = -llapack_LINUX -lblas_LINUX3 -lf2c 

# ----------------------------------------------------
# Java JNI (Java Native Interface) includes/libraries
# ----------------------------------------------------

JAVA_BASE = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ INCS_DIR_JNI =
-I$(JAVA_BASE)/include -I$(JAVA_BASE)/include/linux
```

I have already tried to do a symlink (not sure if I did it right though), and to run it as root.
Can anybody help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: install `liblapack-dev` and `libblas-dev` and try